# Laravel best way to call a controller inside a view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a page who contains children blocs.
Each blocs need to have a specific render (with specific template).
For this i had to use @php in my blade template.

This is my code :

**PageController.php**

```php
public function edit(Page $page)
{
    return view('pages.edit', compact('page')); 
}
```

**View page/edit.blade.php**

```html
<section id="contents" class="contents ui-sortable">
    @foreach ($page->blocs as $bloc)
        @php
            echo $bloc->id;
            echo App\Http\Controllers\BlocController::renderBloc($bloc);
        @endphp
    @endforeach
</section>
```

**BlocController.php**

```php
public static function renderBloc(Bloc $bloc) {
    echo $bloc->id;
    return view('blocs.show.' . $bloc->bloc_type, [
        'bloc' => $bloc, 
        'data' => json_decode($bloc->data)
    ]);
}
```

And then an exemple of bloc

**resources/views/blocs/show/text.blade.php**

```
@extends('blocs.show')
@section('bloc')
{{ $bloc->id }} 
@endsection
```

**resources/views/blocs/show.blade.php**

```html
<section class="bloc bloc_{{ $bloc->bloc_type }}" data-bid="{{ $bloc->id }}">
    {{$bloc->id}}
    @yield('bloc')
</section>
```

I have 2 problems with this :

- I think it's not really a good way to do ? I don't like to use @php in template. I would love to have an opinion about this ? Maybe i need to use a Service Provider ?
- The $bloc->id inside the template (resources/views/blocs/show/text.blade.php) is wrong (it shows the id of the first child bloc in the foreach, even if all my echo $bloc->id before display the good id (page/edit/blade.php, BlocController.php, resources/view/blocs/show.blade.php). This is an other proof i'm doing something wrong i guess ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use controller in your views, it means only that you have not so good architecture. Laravel's Blade easily can do what you try to solve via controller.

You can use `@include` with parameters and get rid of `@php`:

**resources/views/pages/edit.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($page->blocs as $bloc)
  @include('blocs.show', ['bloc' => $bloc])
@endforeach
```

**resources/views/blocs/show.blade.php**

```
<section class="bloc bloc_{{ $bloc->bloc_type }}" data-bid="{{ $bloc->id }}">
    {{$bloc->id}}
    @include('blocs.show.' . $bloc->bloc_type, [
                        'bloc' => $bloc,
                        'data' => json_decode($bloc->data)
                    ])
</section>
```

**resources/views/blocs/show/text.blade.php**

```
Bloc ID = {{ $bloc->id }}
Bloc Text = {{ $data->text }}
```

Comment: Thank, this is amazing !
I still have the problem about the value it displays in the child template (always shows the first Id of the list for all the elements). Do you have an idea ? 

**resources/views/blocs/show/text.blade.php**
@extends('blocs.show')
@section('bloc')

Bloc ID = {{ $bloc->id }}
Bloc Text = {{ $data->text }}

@endsection

Exemple with 4 blocs : 
Bloc ID = 154 Bloc Text = text first bloc
Bloc ID = 154 Bloc Text = text first bloc
Bloc ID = 154 Bloc Text = text first bloc
Bloc ID = 154 Bloc Text = text first bloc

I think the problem is about the yield()

Comment: are you sure? it should'n happen when you'll rewrite code as i suggested

Comment: Yes, this is weird.
If i display {{$bloc->id}} in resources/views/blocs/show.blade.php i have the correct value.
But if i display {{$bloc->id}} in  resources/views/blocs/show/text.blade.php it displays always the first id. 
Something about yield() ?
Should i create a new post for this specific problem ?

Comment: I found a way, i don't use yield, just include. I'm gonna edit your reply